# Why RandomForestClassifier doesn't have cost_complexity_pruning_path method?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In trying to prevent my [Random Forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) model from overfitting on the training dataset, I looked at the `ccp_alpha` parameter.
I do notice that it is possible to tune it with a hyperparameter search method (as `GridSearchCV`).

I discovered that there is a [Scikit-Learn tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_cost_complexity_pruning.html) for tuning this `ccp_alpha` parameter for [Decision Tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#) models.
The methodology described uses the `cost_complexity_pruning_path` method of the Decision Tree model. [This section](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#minimal-cost-complexity-pruning) explains well how the method works. I understand that it seeks to find a sub-tree of the generated model that reduces overfitting, while using values of `ccp_alpha` determined by the `cost_complexity_pruning_path` method.

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
path = clf.cost_complexity_pruning_path(X_train, y_train)
ccp_alphas, impurities = path.ccp_alphas, path.impurities
```

However, I wonder why the Random Forest model type in Scikit-Learn does not implement these `ccp_alpha` selection and pruning concept.
Would it be possible to do this with a little tinkering?
It seems more logical to me than trying to find a good value by searching for hyperparameters (whatever one you use..)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it probably belongs on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: okay, created it : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/103796/why-randomforestclassifier-doesnt-have-cost-complexity-pruning-path-method